# Smart Filter Chips not displaying Oracle APEX Version 23.1.0

Tags: oracle-apex

I just upgraded to apex version 23.1 from 20.2 and am trying to use a Smart Filters Region.  My Smart Filters region contains a search region and two additional checkbox group filters.  The search filter seems to display correctly and the two additional filters show up within a drop down when using the search filter, but my two additional filters do not show up in the Chips region under the search bar as I have seen in every demo of a smart filters region.

Upon loading the pages the suggested chips seem to flash for a brief bit then disappear.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your upgrade, did you refresh your applications' theme style ? That would be my first guess. Every app version has a corresponding theme version. If there are changes in apex functionality, there usually are a number of css changes as well. Those css changes are reflected in the theme. If the theme version does not match the apex version, there can be unwanted side effects. Check the [migration guide](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/migration-guide) for instructions.

Comment: I had not refreshed the theme style prior to upgrading, but after following the instructions and confirming that my applications universal theme is current, I still get the same issue

Comment: In that case I can't help you. I'd post this on forums.oracle.com maybe it's a known issue.